# Fit fieldsets height to td

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following code:

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    row1
                    <br/>
                    row2
                    <br/>
                    row3
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    row1
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    row1
                    <br/>
                    row2
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

and this is what I get:

[image: output html]

What I want is that all the fieldsets get the same height based on biggest fieldset. I tried different ways with css but I can't find a solution.

Comment: That's a horribly unsemantic use of a `fieldset` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` to get desired result.

```css
td, tr, fieldset {
  display: flex;
}
fieldset {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <fieldset>
          row1
          <br/> row2
          <br/> row3
        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td>
        <fieldset>
          row1
        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td>
        <fieldset>
          row1
          <br/> row2
        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td>
        <fieldset>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If don't need table you could change your HTML structure to something like this.

```css
.el,
.el > div,
fieldset {
  display: flex;
}
fieldset {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      row1
      <br/>row2
      <br/>row3
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      row1
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div>
    <fieldset>
      row1
      <br/>row2
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div>
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the table structure which is appropriate here. (flexboxes are also a good solution)

The tds in your row have all the same height, it's just the fieldset that doesn't expand.

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    row1
                    <br/>
                    row2
                    <br/>
                    row3
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    row1
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    row1
                    <br/>
                    row2
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here's some basic styling.